# reset all variable after for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

I would have a for loop which looks like below. After running it once, I would like to reset/delete all outside variable defined(i) as well inside variables(k, p) within the loop after every single increment in i. How can I do it?
I am executing this code in the python interpreter(version 2.7.3) of another program-abaqus(I am not aware if this affects the code).

```
for i in range(10,11):

    mdb.Model(name='model-{}'.format(i), modelType=STANDARD_EXPLICIT)
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=None)
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].partDisplay.setValues(mesh=OFF)
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].partDisplay.meshOptions.setValues(
        meshTechnique=OFF)
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].partDisplay.geometryOptions.setValues(
        referenceRepresentation=ON)
    step = mdb.openStep('C:/temp/Circular_knit - 2, 3, {}.STEP'.format(i), 
    scaleFromFile=OFF)
    mdb.models['model-{}'.format(i)].PartFromGeometryFile(name='Circular_knit - 
    2, 3, {}'.format(i),
        geometryFile=step, combine=False, retainBoundary=True,
        mergeSolidRegions=True, dimensionality=THREE_D, type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
    p = mdb.models['model-{}'.format(i)].parts['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 
    {}'.format(i)]
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=p)
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].view.fitView()
    p = mdb.models['model-{}'.format(i)].parts['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 
    {}'.format(i)]
    all_edges = []
    for j in p.edges:
        all_edges.append(j)
    k=tuple(all_edges)
    p.WireFromEdge(edgeList=(k))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "non-explicitly defined variables"? Using `p = ` and `k = ` is explicitly defining a variable. Also, what do you mean by "reset/delete"? `del p`, `del k`, and `del i` should be what you're looking for (though I don't understand why you would need to delete these variables).

Comment: Python 2.73 has reached it's out of life date over a year ago. Try upgrading to the latest version of Python.

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Put the code inside a function.

Comment: @quamrana :I apologise and still learning to this forum's rules. have edited and added indentation using four spaces.

Comment: @Seth: When the loop runs with i increasing from say 9-10, then other variables are not updated, therefore I would like to reset all variable after every single iteration/increment

Answer (score 0):

Use a class object, your variables will only be 'local' see: [class objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) or you use the built-in function:

`del ...`